# What is the meaning of variable!.property and variable?.property? ¿JS TS?

Tags: typescript, variables, properties

What is the meaning of variable!.property and variable?.property?

Example:

const x = variable?.a?.b;

const x = variable.a!.b;

Is it JavaScript ES6 or Typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Francisco. Could you provide some context? Where have you seen this notation?

Comment: Both are TS. The question mark is also since recently part of main JS but the exclamation is definitely TS, so you must be looking at TS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following

```
const x = variable?.a?.b;
```

is valid in both JavaScript (ES2020), and TypeScript (version 3.7.5 onwards). They are both referring to the use of the optional chaining property.

As for,

```
const x = variable.a!.b;
```

It is just TypeScript (non-null assertion). I don't think it is available in JavaScript as of now.

Comment: "*I don't think it is available in JavaScript as of now.*" I doubt it will ever be. Makes no sense in context of JS, since `variable.a!.b` (TS code) directly translates to `variable.a.b` (JS code). The non-null assertion just tells the compiler to continue with the chaining *despite* `a` being suspected to be falsy.